# Final Cut Pro, How to save a selection of a clip to the computer

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have a long video of 24 minutes and I'll only really be using seconds long clips from it. I use the "I" and "O" to select a portion that I like and I was wondering if there was a way to save the selected portion to the computer and as separate project files? I know about auditioning though I don't think it has really worked out too well for me.

Comment: The part of this question that's confusing to me is "as separate project files."  I haven't used FCPX in a while, but I remember that when I was new to it, I wished there were a way to media manage, like there used to be in Final Cut Pro Studio. Come to think of it, I think I even posted a question here about it.  Sadly, I think the answer is still "no," if that was indeed what you were asking.  https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7455/is-is-possible-to-trim-portions-of-clips-in-fcpx-to-save-disk-space.  You can always just export the sub-portion of the clip that you need, though.

Comment: Dang, alright thanks. I suppose I'll just have to do some workarounds or simply not work with large clips in final cut. I'll def try exporting and see how it works. Thanks.